# Page content in the embedded view not fully visible

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to build an app which has several views. The first view shows a list and a "create" button. Upon clicking the create button, a second view is shown.

I want to be able to embed a sub-view into this second view.

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="openui5.view.Framework"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Page id="detailPage"
    showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress=".onBack">
    <Button id="saveButton"
      text="Save"
      type="Accept"
      icon="sap-icon://save"
      press=".onSave" />
    <Button id="nextButton"
      text="Next"
      type="Accept"
      icon="sap-icon://action"
      press=".onNext" />
    <mvc:XMLView viewName="openui5.view.BasicInformation" async="true" />
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

The embedded view:

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="openui5.view.BasicInformation"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Page id="page1">
    <Button id="stuffButton"
      text="Stuff"
      type="Accept"
      icon="sap-icon://save"
      press=".onSave" />
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

I can see the title of the sub-view but no button.

Am I not doing something "special" when trying to embed this sub-view?

Comment: Can you show us your controller?

Comment: You question about the controller sent me off to get the code for the controller.js file. There I saw some logic around a variable called "frag". I feel like a fool.I am not getting this error anymore, however, I do not see my additional button with the ID "stuffButton".

Comment: That is strange, I can see it when I run your code

Comment: Really. I do not. All I see is the title. I don't suppose you have a jsFiddle you have tried it on do you that i can see?

Comment: This question got bumped so many times, I think it's time to resolve it finally. Does this help? --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045 - As suggested in the link, try adding `height="100%"` to the parent as well as embedded view. Also your root view might be missing a root control (`<App>` or `<SplitApp>`). Otherwise, please try to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that future readers can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

we used also fragments for subviews and it worked fine, but i found it a bit cumbersume to put it in a jsfiddle..still it tried, see below. You should not need to have the view tag around your fragment. Your fragment should have the name xx.fragment.xml in your project and does not need a controller.
then you should be able to include it directly as as xml in your xml view

see also https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2c677b574ea2486a8d5f5414d15e21c5.html

Answer (score -1):

As said before, you could use Fragments which are good for "small portions" of content.
Other solution would be including a Shell component with an inner page to your View and then using routing mechanism so content of your "sub-view" would be loaded into this shell page:

**On the main View:**

```
<Shell id="shellContainer" appWidthLimited="false">
    <App id="appContainer" backgroundOpacity="0"></App>
</Shell>
```

**On manifest.json:**

```
"targets": {...
"YourSubViewDestination": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewName": "YourSubViewName",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "appContainer",
                "parent": "YourMainViewDestination"
            }

...}
```

**On your create button action:**

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("YourSubViewDestination", {});
```

You may need some help with routing: [Routing navigation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.9/docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html)